# Create and set permissions on new home folder programmatically

Tags: c#, permissions, directory

I have created an app to standardize user creation for our AD domain.  Now I would like to be able to create, share and set permissions on the folder.  I know how to create a remote folder, but I am unclear on the best way to go about sharing and setting permissions in VB08.

Thanks in advance,

Christopher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is nice tutorial http://weblogs.asp.net/cumpsd/archive/2004/02/08/69403.aspx
and home path you can get from %HOMEPATH% env. variable

Comment: do you really think i can understand smthing from this mess?

Comment: No I don't I am trying to get correct code formatting, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Just so people know what I ended up going with, here is the final successful code to create a remote folder, set NTFS permissions on the folder to full control for the selected user and then create a share on the new folder with full permissions for everyone.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Management;
using System.Security.AccessControl;

public static void CreateFolder(String accountName, String homeFolder)
    {
        String folderName;
        String localfolderpath;
        String shareName;

        try
        {
            folderName = "\\\\server\\c$\\Home\\" + homeFolder + "\\" + accountName;
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);

            localfolderpath = "C:\\Home\\" + homeFolder + "\\" + accountName;
            shareName = accountName + "$";

            FolderACL(accountName, folderName);

            makeShare(localfolderpath, shareName);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static void FolderACL(String accountName, String folderPath)
    {

        FileSystemRights Rights;

        //What rights are we setting?

        Rights = FileSystemRights.FullControl;
        bool modified;
        InheritanceFlags none = new InheritanceFlags();
        none = InheritanceFlags.None;

        //set on dir itself
        FileSystemAccessRule accessRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(accountName, Rights, none, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow);
        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
        dSecurity.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.Set, accessRule, out modified);

        //Always allow objects to inherit on a directory 
        InheritanceFlags iFlags = new InheritanceFlags();
        iFlags = InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit;

        //Add Access rule for the inheritance
        FileSystemAccessRule accessRule2 = new FileSystemAccessRule(accountName, Rights, iFlags, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow);
        dSecurity.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.Add, accessRule2, out modified);

        dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
    }



    private static void makeShare(string filepath, string sharename)
    {
        try
        {
            String servername = "server";
            // assemble the string so the scope represents the remote server
            string scope = string.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", servername);
            // connect to WMI on the remote server
            ManagementScope ms = new ManagementScope(scope);
            // create a new instance of the Win32_Share WMI object
            ManagementClass cls = new ManagementClass("Win32_Share");
            // set the scope of the new instance to that created above
            cls.Scope = ms;
            // assemble the arguments to be passed to the Create method
            object[] methodargs = { filepath, sharename, "0" };
            // invoke the Create method to create the share
            object result = cls.InvokeMethod("Create", methodargs);

            MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
        }
        catch (SystemException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error attempting to create share {0}:", sharename);
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```